# Section title with dash which appears conditionally on whether there is a section title

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I would like to add a dash after the section label but before the section title.  But I would like to do this conditionally on if there is a section title in the first place.

So

```
\section{Merry Christmas}
```

should display

[image: Section A - Merry Christmas]

While

`\section{}`

should display

[image: Section B Empty]

I want this behaviour automatically in a class I am building without having to add the dash manually in the title etc.

How do I do this?

Comment: Which is the underlying class? `article`? What about `\subsection` etc?

Comment: I am using the exam class ... I think it is built on article.  Either way, I don't need subsections for what I am doing.  But this may be shortsighted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Easy, with `titlesec`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec,etoolbox}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {Section \thesection}
  {0pt}
  {\checksectiontitle}

\newcommand{\checksectiontitle}[1]{%
  \ifblank{#1}{}{ -- #1}%
}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}

\begin{document}

\section{Merry Christmas}

\section{}

\end{document}
```

The trick is that the section title is always passed as the argument to the last macro in the final (mandatory) argument to `\titleformat`. I use `\ifblank` of `etoolbox` so also `\section{ }` will print no dash as well.

[image]

If you plan to use `\section*`, you also need

```
\titleformat{name=\section,numberless}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {}
```

Comment: One has to accept this answer, not only for its brevity but also for the fact that it supports \section{ } (with a space).  Excellent.

Comment: You should load titlesec with option `explicit`, if I'm not mistaken. Beautiful answer.

Comment: What does the explicit option do?   Works as is on my setup.

Comment: @Bernard Not at all. The `explicit` option is very rarely needed.

Comment: @MalteseUnderdog: My solution does work with a space too. And it does not need an extra package ;-)

Comment: @egreg: Because the argument is actually used by the auxiliary command?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You are right of course, yours is a great solution too.  But  I don't mind including another package.  Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 4):

A solution with one extra package only: `xpatch` (or `etoolbox`, will be sufficient here too)

Normally, patching `\@sect` would be sufficient, but using a direct copy of `\@sect` from `latex.ltx` is easier, in my point of view.

`\@seccntformat` uses an ugly `\quad` if the `--` is to be applied, so I removed this.

I did not change the entry to the ToC however and the page header style.

It will be much easier to adapt this solution to other sectioning levels too if this needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\makeatletter


\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
  \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
  \refstepcounter{#1}%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{section}{%
    \ifblank{#8}{%
      \protected@edef\@svsec{Section \@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
    }{%
      \def\@localseccntformat##1{\csname the##1\endcsname}%   
      \protected@edef\@svsec{Section \@localseccntformat{#1}\ -- \relax}%
    }%
  }{%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
  }%
  \fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #6{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
        \interlinepenalty \@M#8\@@par}%
    \endgroup
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
      \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
      \fi
      #7}%
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #6{\hskip #3\relax
      \@svsec #8}%
      \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
          \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
        \fi
        #7}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#5}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{A section}
\section{}
\subsection{First subsection}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another solution quite similar as the second one :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\newcommand{\titcon}[1]
{
  \ifstrempty{#1}
  {}
  { -- #1}
}

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries\Large}{Section \Alph{section} \titcon{#1}}{6pt}{}

\begin{document}

\section{Merry Christmas}

\section{}

\end{document}
```

You can control the argument by using explicit option of the titlesec package.

Comment: you'll need a `numberless` version